# Apply filter function to all divs (visible+invisible)

Tags: jquery

I have created a filter to filter products based on their reviews using jquery. When the select box value change, a jquery event is called which gets selected star from select box selected value.

And here is `if/else` statement,

```
if(stars == 'all'){
    $('#results > div.stars').fadeIn(450);
} else{
    $('#results > div.stars').filter(function(){
         return $(this).attr('stars') != stars
    }).fadeOut(450);   
}
```

Now it works pretty well but there is a small issue. When I filter second time, it doesn't include all products (just includes `divs` with `display:block` properties)

**Example:**
First I filter by 5 stars then filter again by 4 and now if I change back to 5 stars then it doesn't work until I filter them all (`if` condition runs and set all `divs` to `display:block`)

**Tries:**
I tried to `fadeIn` all `divs` before filtering them but it looks awful. I also tried to hide parent `div` and apply filter then show parent `div` but it also doesn't look good.

**Question:** So, what is the proper way to handle this scenario?

**Example Snippet:**

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#byStars', function () {
    var stars = jQuery(this).val();

    if(stars == 'all'){
        jQuery('div[stars]').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
        jQuery('div[stars]').filter(function(){
            return jQuery(this).attr('stars') != stars
        }).fadeOut(450);
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='byStars' class='col-md-2 pull-right'>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
  <option value='5'>5 Star</option>
  <option value='4'>4 Star</option>
  <option value='3'>3 Star</option>
  <option value='2'>2 Star</option>
  <option value='1'>1 Star</option>
  <option value='0'>0 Star</option>
</select>

<div stars="5">5</div><br/>
<div stars="4">4</div><br/>
<div stars="3">3</div><br/>
<div stars="2">2</div><br/>
<div stars="1">1</div><br/>
```

Comment: Please provide enough basic code and html to create a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduce the issue

Comment: For each of the examples and tries... show us the code you tried, and give us a full explanation of what happened... "didn't work" / "doesn't look good" isn't quite enough for us to tell what you saw, or what you expected to see instead ;)

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `jQuery('div[stars]').show();` before `if/else` so that you always have full set, before applying the filter:

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#byStars', function() {
  var stars = jQuery(this).val();
  if (stars == 'all') {
    jQuery('div[stars]').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    jQuery('div[stars]').filter(function() {
      jQuery(this).attr('stars') != stars ? jQuery(this).hide() : jQuery(this).show();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='byStars' class='col-md-2 pull-right'>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
  <option value='5'>5 Star</option>
  <option value='4'>4 Star</option>
  <option value='3'>3 Star</option>
  <option value='2'>2 Star</option>
  <option value='1'>1 Star</option>
  <option value='0'>0 Star</option>
</select>

<div stars="5">5</div>
<div stars="4">4</div>
<div stars="3">3</div>
<div stars="2">2</div>
<div stars="1">1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as mentioned in question that I tried `fadeIn` before `if/else` and it works but it shows all content and then filtered content so there is an animation which doesn't looks good at all.

Comment: I have the updated the answer, though its unclear on how and what exactly do you want animate?

Comment: thank you so much, it works if we use `hide()` & `show()` instead of `fadeIn/fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had to just have to fade in the clicked item before you can hide the others. I added a snippet. I hope it helps.

```js
$(".selectMe").on("click", function(){

  var stars = "all";
  
  stars = $(this).attr('data-id');
  

  if(stars == 'all'){
  
      $('#results > div.stars').fadeIn(450);
      
  } else {
      
      $('#results').find("[data-stars='"+stars+"']").fadeIn(450); //added this in to fade in selected before hide others below.
           
      $('#results > div.stars').filter(function(){
           
           return $(this).attr('data-stars') != stars;
           
      }).fadeOut(450);   
      
  }
  
});
```

```css
.stars {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='selectMe' data-id="all">all</button>
<button class='selectMe' data-id="fiveStars">5</button>
<button class='selectMe' data-id="fourStars">4</button>
<button class='selectMe' data-id="threeStars">3</button>
<button class='selectMe' data-id="twoStars">2</button>
<button class='selectMe' data-id="oneStar">1</button>

<div id="results">
RESULTS:
  <div class="stars" data-stars='oneStars'>1 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='twoStars'>2 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='threeStars'>3 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='fourStars'>4 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='fiveStars'>5 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='fiveStars'>5 stars</div>
  <div class="stars" data-stars='oneStar'>1 stars</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks but problem still exist because it shows all and then filters. These are numbers for reference and in real environment I have div with title, description, image, review so it doesn't looks good when all shows before filtering